# Combine XML files inside a folder into one XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, multithreading, merge

I have like a hundred of XMLs that look like the below example, I wanted to create a code in VB.NET that combine these files into one.

```
<report>
<Host>10.10.10.4</Host>
<Ping>True</Ping>
<PingResult>True</PingResult>
<start>27/08/2014 14:11:17</start>
<end>27/08/2014 14:11:22</end>
<id>86</id>
<Total>00:00:05</Total>
<success>False</success>
</report>

<report>
<Host>10.10.10.5</Host>
<Ping>True</Ping>
<PingResult>True</PingResult>
<start>27/08/2014 14:11:41</start>
<end>27/08/2014 14:11:58</end>
<id>86</id>
<Total>00:00:17</Total>
<success>False</success>
</report>
```

Function to write the XMLs:

```
Private Sub writeReport(result As Boolean, PingResult As Boolean, IpRangePing As Boolean, iSpan As TimeSpan, StartTime As DateTime, EndTime As DateTime, err As Boolean)
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Me.FilePath + "\report")) Then
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory((Me.FilePath + "\report"))
End If
Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(Me.FilePath + "\report\" + Me.Id.ToString + Me.HostName + ".xml", Nothing)

writer.WriteStartDocument()

writer.WriteStartElement("report")

writer.WriteElementString("Host", Me.HostName.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("Ping", IpRangePing.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("PingResult", PingResult.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("start", StartTime.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("end", EndTime.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("id", Me.Id.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("Error", err.ToString)
writer.WriteElementString("Total", iSpan.Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
              iSpan.Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
              iSpan.Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c))
writer.WriteElementString("success", result.ToString)
writer.WriteEndElement()
writer.Close()
End Sub
```

And my plan is to use for each and read all XMLs and then create a new one.

```
Dim directory As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Me.FilePath + "\report\")
Dim xmlFiles As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory .GetFiles("*.xml")
For Each xmlFile As System.IO.FileInfo In xmlFiles
  //To Do
Next
```

Comment: Could you list some code that you already tried to do this with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution, I have to create one function to merge the output files, another to create the list of files to be merged, and the least but not least the xsl that I've found here: http://p2p.wrox.com/83450-post4.html Thanks to joefawcett

```
Private Sub MergeReports(filename As String, stylesheet As String)
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(filename)

Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Item")
If elemList.Count.Equals(Me.TotalItems) Then
  'Create the XslTransform and load the style sheet.
  Dim settings As New XsltSettings(True, True)
  Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
  xslt.Load(stylesheet, settings, Nothing)
  ' Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
  xslt.Transform(filename, "C:\NW\out\report\output.xml")
End If
End Sub


Private Sub CreateList()
Try
  If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(Me.FilePath + "\report\list.xml")) Then
    Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(Me.FilePath + "\report\list.xml", Nothing)
    writer.WriteStartDocument()
    writer.WriteStartElement("Data")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Root", "Root")
    writer.WriteStartElement("fileList")
    writer.WriteElementString("Item", Me.HostName.ToString)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.Close()
  Else
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load(Me.FilePath + "\report\list.xml")
    With xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Data/fileList").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
      .WriteElementString("Item", Me.FilePath + "\report\" + Me.HostName.ToString)
      .Close()

    End With
    xmlDoc.Save(Me.FilePath + "\report\list.xml")
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="{Data/@Root}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/List/Item"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Item">    
 <xsl:copy-of select="document(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

List of files:

```
<Data Root="Root">
  <List>
    <Item>C:\NW\out\report\File1.xml</Item>
    <Item>C:\NW\out\report\File2.xml</Item>
    <Item>C:\NW\out\report\File3.xml</Item>
  </List>
</Data>
```